# Fastlane & Powershell two factor authentication

Tags: powershell, fastlane

Running fastlane in Powershell and try to get environment variable set by [fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#web-sessions).

I have the following code, that I am trying to use to get the variable, but the `FASTLANE_SESSION` is empty after the loop - that is why I try to set an `env` myself in the loop:

```
fastlane spaceauth -u user@domain.com 2>&1 | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $env:FASTLANE_SESSION
    return $_
  }
```

Any ideas for solving this?

Comment: I'm not sure where this is failing from the details given. Is the `$env:my` variable empty or is the `$env:FASTLANE_SESSION` empty in the loop?

Comment: Thanks, the FASTLANE_SESSION is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last line of the `fastlane` output is empty, e.g., line feed(s), that's what you get. Don't have `fastlane`, so tested with `java` instead. First test for `[string]` like your example:

```
java -version 2>&1 | foreach { if ($_ -is [string]) { return $_; } } | select -Last 1;
```

no output.

Second test for non-whitespace characters:

```
java -version 2>&1 | where { $_ -match '\S+' } | select -Last 1;
```

outputs the currently installed version.

For your specific example something like this should work:

```
$OUTPUT = fastlane spaceauth -u email@adomain.com 2>&1 | 
    where { $_ -match '\S+' } | 
    select -Last 1;
```

Comment: @ChrisG. - Updated answer.